# How to mutually exclude two events (mutually exclusive events) in C# WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, wpf-4.0

Consider a sample WPF application which has a Image Viewer with a scroll. 
User can scoll through images by pressing arrow keys as well as through mouse scroll.

How to mutually exclude these two events Keydown and MouseWheel. ?

During MouseWheel(scroll) event, key down event should not work and vice versa.

I have tried using flags but it doesn't work out.

Sample code that I tried out.

```
internal bool KeyPress; // by default false
   internal bool IsMouseScrollActive; // by default false
   private void Grid_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!KeyPress)
        {
            IsMouseScrollActive = true;
            // event handlers here
            IsMouseScrollActive = false;
        }
    }

    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Left:
            case Key.Down:                    
            case Key.Right:
            case Key.Up:
                if (!IsMouseScrollActive)
                {
                    KeyPress = true;
                     // event handlers here
                }
                break;
        }
    }



    private void Window_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Key)
        {
            case Key.Left:
            case Key.Down:
            case Key.Right:
            case Key.Up:
                if (!IsMouseScrollActive)
                {
                    KeyPress = false;
                    // event handlers here
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `During MouseWheel(scroll) event, key down event should not work and vice versa.`? Do you want the events `Grid_MouseWheel` and `Window_KeyDown` not to be fired at the same time or something else?

Comment: yes. the event handlers should not get fired simultaneously when one is occuring.

Comment: The default behaviour of event handler satisfies your condition

Answer (score 0):

using your notation:

```
private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
     if (IsMouseScrollActive)
           e.Handled = true;   //will cancel KeyDown event   

}
```

similar logic applies to your scroll or key up events...